# Разбиение на части js

Tags: javascript

у меня есть к примеру строка 'hello,world:my;name', мне нужно получить массив ['hello', 'world', 'my', 'name']. Через split не получится т. к. там можно ввести только 1 символ или сроку. При повторном использовании split появляется внутренний массив и из-за этого выходит ошибка. Что делать?

Comment: split принимает также регулярку на вход - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split - "Параметр separator может быть как строкой, так и регулярным выражением"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения можно как-то так:

```js
let arr = 'hello,world:my;name'.split(/,|;|:\s*/)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через регулярки (`regExp`).
Создаешь шаблон "Все буквы", включаешь глобальную видимость и с помощью какого-то метода получаешь массив всех вхождений.
Кстати, сами подмассивы можно уравнять с помощью метода `flat`, просто для информации.